# jQuery disabled buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
<div id="notattending"><input type="submit" value="Not Attending" /></div>
```

`notattending` is defined as a jQuery buttonset.

Which attribute or how can I grey it out as if it was disabled? I tried adding `disabled="disabled"` but it didn't change anything visually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the input type to `radio` instead of `submit` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Not Attending" id="mybutton"/>
$('#mybutton').attr('disabled', true);
```

BTW, I don't mean to be offensive, but if you search google with "jquery disable button" you would have found the answer for less than a minute.

Also disabled="disabled" should work:

```
<input type="submit" value="Not Attending" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Comment: As I wrote above, adding disabled="disabled" is in fact disabling the button, but it does not change it visually, which is what i'm looking for.. I did use google and found your solution, but it's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: The problem was because the input was type=submit, if I change it to type=radio the disabled="disabled" appears visually as disabled.

Comment: It should work with submit also. Copy and paste the last line from my post above in a new html file (it can be without anything else), save it and open it with a browser. It should work. If it doesn't, I would be curious to know which browser is it.

Comment: I went here http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/ and I modified the middle button to `<input type="submit" value="A submit button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="true" disabled="disabled">` without any visible clue - the asker said the button was in a jQuery button set